# Celery: Dictionary not getting updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, celery

status.py

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manag = Manager()
serviceLock = manag.Lock()
status_list = manag.dict()
```

cel.py

```
from celery import Celery 
import status     
app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(req, x, y):
    status.status_list[req] = 'performing request'
    return (x+y)
```

main.py

```
 from cel import add
 import status

 req = 1
 status.status_list[req] = 'request generated'
 print(status.status_list)
 add.delay(req, 4, 4)
 print(status.status_list)
```

So I am having this weird output. it shows the same list everytime. The list is not getting updated for some reason. 
The output is

```
{1 : 'request generated'}
{1 : 'request generated'}
```

But what I need is

```
{1 : 'request generated'}
{1 : 'performing request'}
```

All the workers share the same dictionary. I could check that in my celery terminal. But the main process and celery have their own local dictionaries. Can someone help me on how to have a unified dictionary.